# Is there a way to manually trigger Visual Studio to update .csproj files?

Tags: visual-studio, csproj

I sometimes lose my pending changes to the .csproj file. I'm left with a changeset of new files, which still carry the appended [add] tag in the Team Explorer, but pending updates to the .csproj file are wiped out.

I can manually edit the .csproj to add them, but this is tedious and error-prone. Is there a way to re-run whatever process normally updates the .csproj file automatically?

Comment: Why can’t you just resolve the conflict by merging  the csproj file?

Comment: My team is very large so ideally I would just grab the server version and then have VS re-run my local changes rather than click through to merge every single new add.

As for why VS can't auto-merge these changes, I'm not sure either :)

Comment: "When resolving conflicts I sometimes lose my pending changes to the .csproj file", then I think the real task for you is to study how to properly resolve conflicts (not easy, but can be done).

Comment: Those first three words seem to be problematic so I've removed them from the post. More generally I am curious if this tool exists.

Comment: "Rerun whatever process updates the .csproj automatically" I am not sure what process you think updates the .csproj automatically. As I understand it, it is updated when you manually make a change, e.g. by adding a file, and that is it. There is no automated process. How would it even know what to add?

Comment: "There is no automated process" answers my question, thanks. The changes are still tracked by Visual Studio because they are visible in the explorer and marked with an [add] tag. What I wanted was a way to get Visual Studio to run through the list of [added] files and ensure they're accounted for in the .csproj.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, changes to .csproj files should be very rare, when using the new SDK style projects.

Since by default, all .cs files are included, you do not normally need any update to the project file if files are added or removed. So I suggest you remove all `<Compile Add/Include/Update />` lines that refer to code as well as the line that says `<EnableDefaultCompileItems>false</EnableDefaultCompileItems>` if you have that.

For most projects that works just fine. It will reduce the frequency of changes to the project file significantly (and make it a lot easier to read).

Comment: This seems like a good answer. Unfortunately we're using a different setup (which I don't have control over) so every file addition or subtraction triggers a change to the .csproj. Thanks.

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline I would recommend this update (if you still use the old project setup) as soon as possible. You will get more and more problems if you stick to older formats going forward (also e.g. with dependency management)